# How to add a pointer towards the text using the tailwind css for the PopoverPanel of the headlessui/vue?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I am developing a custom tooltip menu which shows some tooltips on the hover of the text. As per my requirement, I want to add a pointer to my tooltip which points to the text on which hovered when showing the tooltip information.

To build the tooltip menu I have made use of the `@headlessui/vue` within my `Nuxt 3` application. Everything works fine but the only problem is that I am unable to add a pointer towards the text for my `PopoverPanel`. Can someone please let me know how to add a pointer towards the text?

Following is the code I have which shows the tooltip menu on hover over the text in nuxt 3 composition api:

```
<template>
  <Popover v-slot="{ open, close }" class="h-0">
    <PopoverButton class="focus:outline-none">
      <p
        @mouseover.native.stop.prevent="hoverPopover($event, open)"
        @mouseleave.native.stop.prevent="closePopover($event, close)"
      >
        Hover ME
      </p>
    </PopoverButton>

    <PopoverPanel
      class="absolute z-50 bg-gray-700 rounded-lg text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-normal inline-block ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none"
      @mouseover.native.stop.prevent="popoverHover = true"
      @mouseleave.native.stop.prevent="closePopover($event, close)"
    >
      <slot> Text to be shown on hover over </slot>
    </PopoverPanel>
  </Popover>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel, Portal } from "@headlessui/vue";

const popoverHover = ref(false);
const popoverTimeout = ref();

//On hover show the tooltip with information
const hoverPopover = (e, open) => {
  popoverHover.value = true;
  if (!open) {
    e.target.parentNode.click();
  }
};

//On mouse leave close it
const closePopover = (e, close) => {
  popoverHover.value = false;
  if (popoverTimeout.value) clearTimeout(popoverTimeout.value);
  popoverTimeout.value = setTimeout(() => {
    if (!popoverHover.value) {
      close();
    }
  }, 100);
};
</script>
```

I want to add a pointer towards the text something similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your PopoverPanel, you can use Tailwind to build a caret to indicate your desired pointer. I did a quick test on Tailwind Play to illustrate.

The class you need is: `after:content-[''] after:absolute after:w-0 after:h-0 after:border-4 after:border-gray-700 after:-bottom-1 after:left-1/2 after:-translate-x-1/2 after:rotate-45`

Essentially, your PopoverPanel will now look like:

```
<PopoverPanel
  class="absolute z-50 bg-gray-700 rounded-lg text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-normal inline-block ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none after:content-[''] after:absolute after:w-0 after:h-0 after:border-4 after:border-gray-700 after:-bottom-1 after:left-1/2 after:-translate-x-1/2 after:rotate-45"
  @mouseover.native.stop.prevent="popoverHover = true"
  @mouseleave.native.stop.prevent="closePopover($event, close)"
>
  <slot> Text to be shown on hover over </slot>
</PopoverPanel>
```

You can see my test on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/qK9dNpFieD).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am facing a small problem if I add the max-w and max-h to the PopOverPanel then the pointer disappears for some reason. Is there a way I can fix this? I am adding the following classes: `max-w-md max-h-64 overflow-auto`.

Following is the complete classes to the PopOverPanel:
`rounded-lg text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-normal inline-block ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none after:content-[''] after:absolute after:w-0 after:h-0 after:border-4 after:border-gray-700 after:-left-0 after:top-1/3 after:-translate-x-1/2 after:rotate-45 max-w-md max-h-64 overflow-auto`

Comment: I want to assume the caret is hidden somewhere behind the block. Maybe you can inspect in the browser to have a hovered guess of where the block is hiding. Tough to tell what could be wrong but I'd appreciate if you can put up this part of your project on StackBlitz or Codesandbox. I can have a look and see what's truly wrong there..

Comment: Thanks for your response. You can use the same link that you have provided me: https://play.tailwindcss.com/qK9dNpFieD. Just add the following classes after `rounded-lg` to it to control the size: `max-w-md max-h-28 overflow-auto`. You notice that the arrow created at the bottom disappears.

Comment: I believe its mainly happenning because of the `overflow-auto`. If I remove that it works fine but if the content is large then it comes outside the div. How to add the scrollbar option if content is large?

Comment: Oh I see it. In that case, just simply create another block within the hover container. This block will be the one to carry your height and width constraints.

I have updated the code here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/OXGc7qLjrP